# How do I change my user-agent using Requests Library

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

Im trying to change my user-agent using the code below.  But it gets recognized as "python-requests/2.22.0"

```
from lxml import html
import requests

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/67.0.3396.99 Safari/537.36'
}

page = requests.get('http://www.useragentstring.com/')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

userAgent = tree.xpath('//*[@id="uas_textfeld"]/text()')

print(userAgent[0])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your header,you even didn't add it to your request.

```
page = requests.get('http://www.useragentstring.com/',headers=headers)
```

Now it show me the right user-agent:
[image]